# How can pass string with the “forbidden” response in .net core 2.2 web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1

It's working fine:

```
context.Result = new ForbidResult();
```

But I want to pass a message with **"forbidden”** response like this:

```
context.Result = new ForbidResult("Forbidden");
```

in .net core 2 web API. But when I write this above line of code that time I get

> 500 Internal server error

So, anyone helps me how can I able to perform this above line of code.

Sample Code

```
public class ClaimRequirementFilter : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
          // working code
          context.Result = new ForbidResult();

          // Code with error (500 Internal Server Error)
          context.Result = new ForbidResult("Forbidden");
     }
 }
```

Comment: Looks like the ForbidResult constructor with a string parameter isn't for passing a message, but actually challenging an authentication scheme as seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.forbidresult.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ForbidResult__ctor_System_String_)

Comment: Yes, it is ForbidResult constructor then i am not able to understand why it generates 500 internet server error as a response? @MindSwipe

Comment: Start the server and see what happens when the 500 internal (not internet) server error occurs, there should be an exception being thrown. This is because you cannot pass arbitrary text to the ForbidResult as a parameter

Comment: I perform what you ( @MindSwipe ) say but still, I get 500 internal server error. 
Can you (@MindSwipe) give me a line of working code?

Comment: I'm not telling you to do anything, I am saying that what you are doing is incorrect. To use the string parameter of the ForbidResult you first need to add an authentication scheme to the application, and then use the same name inside the constructor, else it throws an error (as it does here). Also, I cannot give you a working line of code, if I could this would be an answer and not a comment.

Comment: where are you passing context? Or where you are returning response?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I created these two class (1. CustomError & 2. CustomUnauthorizedResult) and used these class to handle Authorization. Here you can pass the dynamic message and status code.

```
public class CustomError
{
    public string Error { get; }

    public CustomError(string message)
    {
        Error = message;
    }
}

public class CustomUnauthorizedResult : JsonResult
{
    public CustomUnauthorizedResult(string message, int statusCode) : base(new CustomError(message))
    {
        StatusCode = statusCode;
    }
}

public class ClaimRequirementFilter : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        context.Result = new CustomUnauthorizedResult("Authorization failed.", statusCode:403);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Simply you can use **ObjectResult** to return a custom response with a status code.

**See the syntax,**

```
return new ObjectResult("Message") {StatusCode = YOUR_STATUS_CODE };
```

**Example:**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] SomeData _data)
{
     // do your stuff

    // return forbidden with custom message
    return new ObjectResult("Forbidden") { StatusCode = 403};
}
```